# Calendar.current.component(.year, from: Date()) returns 4 instead of 2022

Tags: ios, swift

We have a page on our app in which the user can selected a year from a list. The list contains all years from 1900 to 2022.
Some users have reported that they don't see the list at all. We couldn't figure out how this happened, so we added a non-fatal issue report that is sent to Crashlytics whenever the initial conditions for displaying the list aren't met.

This is the relevant code:

```
private lazy var currentYear: Int = {
    Calendar.current.component(.year, from: Date())
}()

private lazy var yearsArray: [String] = {
    if currentYear < 1900 {
        assertionFailure()
        NSError(domain: "OTP_YEAR", code: 1, userInfo: [NSLocalizedDescriptionKey: "CurrentYear < 1900. value: \(currentYear), Date: \(Date())"])
            .reportToExternalServices()
        return []
    }
    let result = (1900 ... currentYear).map { String($0) }
    if result.isEmpty {
        assertionFailure()
        NSError(domain: "OTP_YEAR", code: 2, userInfo: [NSLocalizedDescriptionKey: "Empty years array. currentYear: \(currentYear), Date: \(Date())"])
            .reportToExternalServices()
    }
    if result.contains(where: { $0.trimWhiteSpacesAndNewLine().isEmpty }) {
        assertionFailure()
        NSError(domain: "OTP_YEAR", code: 3, userInfo: [NSLocalizedDescriptionKey: "Years array contains empty strings. currentYear: \(currentYear), Date: \(Date()), Array: \(result)"])
            .reportToExternalServices()
    }
    return result
}()
```

After a few weeks it happened again and this time we could see the following event reported:

```
nserror-code: 1
nserror-domain: OTP_YEAR
NSLocalizedDescription: CurrentYear < 1900. value: 4, Date: 2022-07-11 12:59:00 +0000
```

This happened to two of our users, both with iPhone 13 and iOS 15.5

According to the logs, if I understand them correctly, the standard documented way of extracting the year component, *Calendar.current.component(.year, from: Date())*, returns 4 instead of the current year.

We can't reproduce this situation on our test devices. Any idea why this happens to some of the users?

Comment: `Calendar.current` What are they calendar?

Comment: If `Calendar.current` is the Japanese calendar, 4 is the expected result.

Comment: @Larme Obviously I don't know. I can add this info to the log so the next time, this peace of data will be available

Comment: See https://pastebin.com/1t2MQeNX that you can also test, but the Japanese Calendar seems to be the reason of your unexpectetd behavior.

Comment: Remember when using `Date` and related (like `Calendar`): Not everyone use your year calculation (now it's 2022 vs ...?), not everyone use the same day as the "start of the day" (Monday vs Sunday), not everyone has the same timeZone (UTC + 0, UTC +X), not every "hours exists" (Day savelight, etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.current may give unexpected results if the device is set the a different calendar. Use Calendar(identifier: .gregorian) like this :

```
Calendar(identifier: .gregorian).component(.year, from: Date())
```